# Django forms - как сделать неактивным виджет при выборе одной из опций в ChoiseField, например?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-model

Django forms - как сделать неактивным виджет при выборе одной из опций в ChoiseField ?
то есть у меня есть виджет ChoiseField , в нём два условия. И нужно при выборе одного из условий чтобы деактивировалось другое поле, например TextField.
[image: Скриншот с примером формы и Что должно быть в итоге]

Comment: Можно попробовать в классе формы, внутри class Meta создать поле с виджетом, в котором подключить событие: **widgets = {
            "text_field": forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': "Load();"})
        }**. В классе админ переопределить форму и переопределить шаблон change_form.html. И дальше в javascript попробовать отключить. На счет отключить точно не уверен. Но, обработчик срабатывает и текстовое значение поля я получал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такое решение помогло: Добавляем такой класс в файле admin.py в вашем классе

```
@admin.register(Ваша_модель)
class Ваша_модель_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
```

(Запятая в конце обязательна, потому что это кортеж -без неё будет ошибка):

```
   class Media:
        js = (  'path_to_file/js/disable_db_widget.js',)
```

и такой скрипт (может кому-то пригодится):

```
(function($) {

        console.log('From test3.js ');


    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#id_IS_PATH').change(function() {

            if ($(this).val() == '1' || $(this).val() == '2') {

                console.log($(this))


                $('#id_DB_SERVICE').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#id_DB_SERVICE').closest('.form-row').addClass('disabled-field');
                $('#id_DB_SERVICE').val( '41');
            } else {
                $('#id_DB_SERVICE').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#id_DB_SERVICE').closest('.form-row').removeClass('disabled-field');
            }
        });
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

В Django, для создания формы с динамическим поведением - как деактивация поля при выборе опции в ChoiceField, можно использовать JavaScript в сочетании с Django формами

```
<!-- Пример кода для формы -->
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="{% url 'my_url' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.my_choice_field }}
    {{ form.my_text_field }}
</form>
    <script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const choiceField = document.getElementById("id_my_choice_field");
    const textField = document.getElementById("id_my_text_field");
choiceField.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if (choiceField.value === 'option_A') {
            textField.disabled = true;  // Деактивация поля
        } else {
            textField.disabled = false;  // Активация поля
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Добрый день. Я нашёл на сайте с ДЖанго-доками похожую информацию. Там тоже предлагают выполнения js-скрипта через класс Media. Например:     class Media:
        js = ('db_field_disable.js'). Только ошибку выдаёт - типа не найден путь к файлу

Comment: @михакапа Не знаю, а Вы подключили в настройках проекта путь к статичным файлам (static) ?

Comment: да, всё добавил. STATIC_DIR = BASE_DIR / "static/" STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static") ] –